# htaccess make dynamic url to static url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL like:

```
http://localhost/admin-s/index.php?m=user
```

However, I would like a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/admin-s/user
```

I try like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+).php$ index.php?nol&m=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ user%1.php [L]
```

How to make it?

Comment: It’s not really clear what you want to do: do you want to rewrite `http://localhost/admin-s/index.php?m=user` to `http://localhost/admin-s/user` (and if so, do you want to do just an internal rewrite or a redirect?) or the other way around? Which of these two should be the URL the user sees in their browser?

Comment: i used an ajax, in folder user, i have three file: user.php (this is like index.php), user_crud.php (for CRUD in php), user_ss.php (server side), i want user see just localhost/admin-s/user

Answer (score 2):

Hope this simple configuration will help you out. You can check this configuration [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

This will redirect request of this pattern from `http://localhost/admin-s/index.php?m=user` to `http://localhost/admin-s/user`

**Explanation:**

> **1.** If `REQUEST_URI` is `/admin-s/index.php`
>
> **2.** If `QUERY_STRING` is `m=someWords`
>
> **3.** Redirect to `/admin-s/someWords`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/admin\-s\/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=([\w]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin-s/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hi, it't work. but im still error, the url i'll rederect to `localhost/admin-s/user/user.php`

Comment: if (isset($_GET['m']) == NULL) {
                        include 'home.php';
                    } elseif ($_GET['m'] == 'user') {
                        include './user/user.php';
                    }

Comment: and you expected output is `include 'home.php'; ` right?

Comment: try this `.htaccess` in in-cognito mode of browser It will work fine, You can check http://htaccess.mwl.be/ just put my .htaccess code here and try with any  url.

Comment: your `.htaccess` is true. but i've problem with `isset`. `if (isset($_GET['m']) == NULL) {
                        include 'home.php';
                    } elseif ($_GET['m'] == 'user') {
                        include './user/user.php';
                    } elseif ($_GET['m'] == 'model') {
                        include './model/model.php';
                    }`

Comment: try to change this `if (isset($_GET['m']) == NULL) ` to `if (!isset($_GET['m'])) {  ...  } ` and let me know is it working

Comment: in index.php, i have bootstrap, jquery, etc. so, if redirect to `localhost/admin-s/user` contain bootstrap, jquery, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143672/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-wawan-setiyawan).

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered here : [How to turn dynamic URL into static URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692298/how-to-turn-dynamic-url-into-static-url)

For your problem may be try following rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin-s/([^-]+) /index.php?m=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Let us know if it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule in your **root/.htaccess** or **/admin-s/.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect /admin-s/index.php?m=user to /admin-s/user
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin-s/index\.php\?m=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /admin-s/%1? [L,R]
#rewrite the new uri back to the orignal location
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:admin-s/)?(.+)$ /admin-s/index.php?m=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for answer mate, but i've problem in `isset. if (isset($_GET['m']) == NULL) { include 'home.php'; } elseif ($_GET['m'] == 'user') { include './user/user.php'; } elseif ($_GET['m'] == 'model') { include './model/model.php'; }`

Comment: in index.php, contain bootstrap, jquery, etc. so, index.php must be load when user see `localhost/admin-s/user`

Answer (score 1):

Try below in your `admin-s` direcotry,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?m=$1 [L]
```